# Procedure sql server, retornar o valor total de um id

Tags: sql-server

Tenho um banco de produtos vendidos formando por id, nome e valor. Gostaria de fazer uma procedure que retornasse total de cada produto que foi vendido. Algem sabe como se faz isso?

Que o resultado sege

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mouse = 60
CPU = 1500
Teclado = 100

Comment: Pode colocar sua sentença na pergunta?

Comment: Coloque a estrutura de sua tabela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explicação

Você pode utilizar a função de agregação `SUM()` para somar os valores e agrupar os resultados através do nome dos produtos com a cláusula  `GROUP BY`.

## Query

```
SELECT 
    nome_produto [Nome do Produto],
    SUM(valor_produto) [Valor Total]
FROM
   produtos_vendidos
GROUP BY
   nome_produto
```